# reading array of ascending order of keys in the certain range

Tags: php

```
Array
(
[selectCat1] => 'somevalue'
[selectSubCat1] => 'somevalue'
[heading1] => 'somevalue'
[filename1] => 'somevalue'
[orderBox1] => 'somevalue'
[selectCat3] => 'somevalue'
[selectSubCat3] => 'somevalue'
[heading3] =>  'somevalue'
[filename3] => 'somevalue'
[orderBox3] => 'somevalue'
[selectCat4] => 'somevalue'
[selectSubCat4] => 'somevalue'
[heading4] => 'somevalue'
[filename4] => 'somevalue'
[orderBox4] =>  'somevalue'
[selectCat5] => 'somevalue'
[selectSubCat5] => 'somevalue'
[heading5] => 'somevalue'
[filename5] => 'somevalue'
[orderBox5] => 'somevalue'
[selectCat6] => 'somevalue'
[selectSubCat6] => 'somevalue'
[heading6] => 'somevalue'
[filename6] => 'somevalue'
[orderBox6] => 'somevalue'
[selectCat7] => 'somevalue'
[selectSubCat7] => 'somevalue'
[heading7] => 'somevalue'
[filename7] => 'somevalue'
[orderBox7] => 'somevalue'
```

)

In this array values of [selectCat1], [selectSubCat1],[heading1],[filename1],[orderBox1] need to be inserted in one row of DB table ,and [selectCat3],[selectSubCat3],[heading3],[filename3],[orderBox3] in other row.

I cannot use the for loop in the range 1 to 7 because in 1 to 7 some of the keys should be ignored like in this case key 2 is ignored..

I have tried with the following code...

```
end($form_data); //$form_data is above array         
$key = key($form_data);  
$last_entry_no= substr($key,8); //to get the last key number
$count = count($form_data);
$rowsToInsert = $count/5;
for($i=1; $i<=$rowsToInsert; $i++)
{
  foreach ($form_data as $key => $value) {
   echo $key.'<br>';
  }
}
```

This is not working. Please help me with this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
$group = [];

foreach($array as $key => $value){
    $i   = substr($key, -1);
    $key = rtrim($key, $i);

    if(!isset($group[$i])){
        $group[$i] = [];
    }

    $group[$i][$key] = $value;
}
```

In each element of `$group` array you will get key-value pairs of indexed key-group.

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array // group 1
        (
            [selectCat] => somevalue
            [selectSubCat] => somevalue
            [heading] => somevalue
            [filename] => somevalue
            [orderBox] => somevalue
        )

    // no group 2

    [3] => Array // group 3
        (
            [selectCat] => somevalue
            [selectSubCat] => somevalue
            [heading] => somevalue
            [filename] => somevalue
            [orderBox] => somevalue
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [selectCat] => somevalue
            [selectSubCat] => somevalue
            [heading] => somevalue
            [filename] => somevalue
            [orderBox] => somevalue
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [selectCat] => somevalue
            [selectSubCat] => somevalue
            [heading] => somevalue
            [filename] => somevalue
            [orderBox] => somevalue
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [selectCat] => somevalue
            [selectSubCat] => somevalue
            [heading] => somevalue
            [filename] => somevalue
            [orderBox] => somevalue
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [selectCat] => somevalue
            [selectSubCat] => somevalue
            [heading] => somevalue
            [filename] => somevalue
            [orderBox] => somevalue
        )

)
```

Comment: @SagarCh You should supply database information, like table-strucrure and used database engine name so anyone here can help you. However, I believe it might be a reason for checking manuals, or asking another question here. If you believe, that my answer helped you, feel free to upvote it or accept it as an answer.